# What is the proper Derby SQL syntax for this select statement?

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, netbeans, derby

```
String SQL = "SELECT * from USERNAME."LoginTable" ";
```

I have a database named TestDB, I have a schema named USERNAME and I have a table called LoginTable.

The problem I'm having is that I need to use the double quotes in the select statement when I run this query in NetBeans Derby SQL, but I clearly can't use 2 sets of double quotes in Java because it won't recognize that it's a complete String. What is the proper way to write this so I won't have this problem come up again in the future?

Here is the error message thats coming up when I try to run: 
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "\'LoginTable\'" at line 1, column 24.

Comment: You may not need to quote that identifier at all, as nothing looks special about it to me. What happens with just `String SQL = "SELECT * from USERNAME.LoginTable";`?

Comment: Thats the thing, in every example I've found of what the syntax should be, there were no quotes around the table name, but for whatever reason putting quotes around the table name is the only way it would work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can escape double quotes inside a string using backslash.

Eg.

```
String myString = "My String contains \"Double Quotes\"";
```

And if you need a backslash in a string, then escape it with a backslash.

Eg.

```
String oneBackslash = "\\";
```

So yours now becomes

```
String SQL = "SELECT * from USERNAME.\"LoginTable\" ";
```

A lot of database engines I've used allow the use of single quotes too. Just not sure if Derby DB is one of them.